# How do you disable / fix this specific default behavior wherein after you refresh the whole webpage the specific router-link is still selected

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Take a look at this pictures and description that I'm going to describe in the most understandable way possible.... These are my router-links

[image]

and on the side is the router-view / `ProfileView.vue` component that will display the details of that person, just don't mind the reds, it's just that those are very private keys to be displayed online

[image]

How do you disable /fix this specific default behavior wherein after you refresh the whole webpage the specific router-link is still selected and the router-view is invisible. Refreshing the page returns like this

[image]

Comment: How are the routes defined? What is the URL it points to when refreshing?

Comment: This was the route before and after refreshing, because I was refreshing the whole page.. `http://localhost:3000/users#/user/1`,

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to update the `url` with the unique identifier (UUID) once the item get selected. Now when you refresh the page just identify the item using the (UUID) in url and apply the specific item using `active` state. As per the `router-view` case you can easily handle it with the url defined case - make `/profile:id` expect a parameter, which will only provided when you click any of the `router-link` else redirect back to items page with the last selected `UUID` to highlight the last `selected item`

Comment: which part here, sir ? which url should I update something like `location.reload` or the vue-router url ? I don't understand your answer that well, please elaborate more.